# Python: dict comprehension with multiple key-value pairs in the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

The goal: working analogue of expression

```
{k1: v1, k2: v2 for k1, k2, v1, v2 in data}
```

or more particular case `{k1: v, k2: v for k1, k2, v, _ in data}`

that iterates through `data` only **1 time** (in given examples `data` is iterable object of 4-tuples).

(And similar question about list comprehension, e.g. `[myfunc1(v1), myfunc2(v2) for v1, v2 in data]`).

I can suppose only solution using own iterator:

```
def getby(iterable_data, iterable_indexes):
    for indexed_data in iterable_data:
        for tupl in iterable_indexes:
            yield tuple(indexed_data[ind] for ind in tupl)
    raise StopIteration
```

Example of working: `list(getby([('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')], [(0, 1), (2, 1)]))` returns `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'e'), ('f', 'e')]`. 
But possible  it is slow.

I also can suppose equivalent expression for example above in terms of `itertools.chain` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(lst for lst, _ in groupby([('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')],
                                                   lambda lst: [(lst[0], lst[1]), (lst[2], lst[1])])))
```

But possible it is ugly.

ipython-based comparison of two solution: the first *1000 loops, best of 3: **20.2 ms** per loop*, the second *1000 loops, best of 3: **4.12 ms** per loop*, so the second solution really faster. But maybe  is more elegant solution exist?

Comment: Maybe `{k: v for k1, k2, v1, v2 in data for k, v in ((k1, v1), (k2, v2))}`? Particular case: `{k: v for k1, k2, v, _ in data for k in (k1, k2)}`.

Comment: @Delgan, of course! This is really elegant solution that works slightly faster! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, do not forget to accept the @Martijn solution. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comprehension format is strictly limited to *one* result per iteration. You can add extra loops though, to loop over the multiple elements you want to insert:

```
{k: v for k1, k2, v1, v2 in data for k, v in ((k1, v1), (k2, v2))}
```

or your second example:

```
{k: v for k1, k2, v, _ in data for k in (k1, k2)}
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
result = {}
for k1, k2, v1, v2 in data:
    for k in (k1, k2):
        result[k] = v
```

If you can write something out as nested loops, possibly with `if` statements in between, with just *one* statement at the innermost level that assigns a key-value pair, then you can express it in a dictionary comprehension.

You can do this too with `chain.from_iterable()`, but then produce lists or tuples with a sequence of key-value pairs, and pass the result to the `dict()` function:

```
dict(chain.from_iterable(((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) for k1, v1, k2, v2 in data))
dict(chain.from_iterable(((k1, v), (k2, v)) for k1, k2, v, _ in data))
```